# Passing inline double array as method argument

Tags: c++, arrays, pass-by-value, function-parameter

Consider method

```
functionA (double[] arg)
```

I want to pass a double array inline, like

```
functionA({1.9,2.8})
```

and not create an array first and then pass it, like

```
double var[] = {1.0,2.0};
functionA(var);
```

Is this possible with C++? Sounds simple, but I could not find a hint anyway concerning my question which made me suspicious :).

Comment: in C++ **method** is virtual member-function that exists through the hierarchy

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with `std::initializer_list<>`

```
#include<vector>

void foo(const std::initializer_list<double>& d)
{ }

int main()
{
    foo({1.0, 2.0});
    return 0;
}
```

Which compiles and works for me under g++ with `-std=c++0x` specified.

Answer (score 7):

This works with c++0x

```
void functionA(double* arg){
   //functionA
}

int main(){
    functionA(new double[2]{1.0, 2.0});
    //other code
    return 0;
}
```

Although you need to make sure that the memory allocated by new is deleted in the functionA(), failing which you there will be a memory leak!

Comment: Sounds really dangerous to me, I would like to avoid at any cost, it is easy to forget to delete the array

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in C++11 using `std::initializer_list`.

```
void fun(std::initializer_list<double>);
// ...
fun({ 1., 2. });
```

You can't do it in C++03 (or it will involve enough boilerplate it won't be feasible).